# Revoke database-level privileges without the need for "use db_name;" statement

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a MySQL user with database-level privileges.

```sql
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER ON mydb.* TO 'theuser';
```

The user can create tables and insert rows into them.

When the user exceeds the limits, for example, the number of allowed rows in his plan, I want to revoke the `INSERT` privilege. So the user cannot insert new rows into the tables anymore. It's a plan with soft limits.

I know I can execute the following query:

```sql
REVOKE INSERT ON mydb.* FROM 'theuser';
```

But it doesn't affect until the next `use mydb`.

According to MySQL docs:

> A grant table reload affects privileges for each existing client connection as follows:
>
> - Table and column privilege changes take effect with the client's next request.
> - **Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client executes a USE db_name statement.**
> - Global privileges and passwords are unaffected for a connected client. These changes take effect only for subsequent connections.

So my problem is how can I force MySQL to reload database-level privileges without the need for "use db_name" statement, just like table-level privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really nothing you can do to circumvent this. Why ???

Look at your third bulletpoint:

> Global privileges and passwords are unaffected for a connected client. These changes take effect only for subsequent connections.

That bulletpoint is true for a user with `SUPER` privileges or `root@localhost`. Such a user cannot change a live connection's grants in full in the middle of an external or separate session. That has to be true even more so for a non-superuser.

By definition, you should be able to revoke a privilege you could grant.

But look at the grants again

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, ALTER ON mydb.* TO 'theuser';
```

Notice that this user cannot give away its grants. Why not ??? The `WITH GRANT OPTION` is missing. So, `theuser` cannot give away its grants to anyone else.

What you are seeking is the opposite: to revoke the grants. In this case, you are revoking from yourself. Unfortunately, there is no such thing as `WITH REVOKE OPTION`.

Switching to a database with `USE mydb` signals mysqld to trigger the reload of `theuser`'s grants from all the grant tables (`mysql.user`, `mysql.db`, `mysql.tables_priv`, `mysql.columns_priv`). Doing this is far easier to implement that creating an option to revoke grants from a live connection (kinda like unsubscribing from a service that sends you email). Otherwise, grants would more frequently reload grants into RAM for mysqld or into a session's internal buffers. This would introduce some significant read traffic from these tables just for establishing grants.

In light of all this, there are only fours things you can do:

- Do the `USE mydb` (Best Option)
- Code Changes ([Godspeed, Spiderman !!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AglV2jLZ4qU))

  - Disconnect and open a new session
  - Change application to no longer do `SELECT` if the user is `theuser`
  - Use Views, then you can just drops views and trap read errors based on missing views